# Calculate the first day of next month and quarter from today in PHP

Tags: php

For calculating the first dayof next month from today:

```
$firstDayNextMonth = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('first day of next month'));
```

How to calculate the first day of next quarter from today?

- First quarter, Q1: 1 January – 31 March
- Second quarter, Q2: 1 April – 30 June
- Third quarter, Q3: 1 July – 30 September
- Fourth quarter, Q4: 1 October – 31 December

Thank you!

Comment: And when do the quarters start, for you?

Comment: To me they are _Traditionally these are known as “quarter days” and have been in use for centuries. The dates they fall on are – 25th March (Lady Day), 24th June (Midsummer Day), 29th September (Michaelmas) and 25th December (Christmas Day)._

Comment: @RiggsFolly I've added the quarter dates to my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be more elegant ways but this does the trick

```
$today = '2021-12-03';

$now = new DateTimeImmutable($today);
$nowMonth = (int) $now->format('m');
$yr = (int) $now->format('Y');

# Next quarter
echo 'Todays date is ' . $now->format('d/m/Y').PHP_EOL;
switch ($nowMonth){
    case 1:
    case 2:
    case 3:
        $quarter = new DateTimeImmutable("$yr/04/01");
        echo 'Next quarter is ' . $quarter->format('d/m/Y') . PHP_EOL;
        break;
    case 4:
    case 5:
    case 6:
        $quarter = new DateTimeImmutable("$yr/07/01");
        echo 'Next quarter is ' . $quarter->format('d/m/Y') . PHP_EOL;
        break;
    case 7:
    case 8:
    case 9:
        $quarter = new DateTimeImmutable("$yr/10/01");
        echo 'Next quarter is ' . $quarter->format('d/m/Y') . PHP_EOL;
        break;
    case 10:
    case 11:
    case 12:
        $yr++;
        $quarter = new DateTimeImmutable("$yr/01/01");
        echo 'Next quarter is ' . $quarter->format('d/m/Y') . PHP_EOL;
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As quarters can be different for different people I think you will need to define in code what your quarters are.

Then it is just a case of determining the current quarter and if the next quarter is in the new year or not:

```
//define our quarters
$quarters = array(
1 => '01-01',
2 => '04-01',
3 => '07-01',
4 => '10-01'
);

$month = date("n"); //get current month as a number

$currentQuarter = ceil($month / 3); //get the current quarter

echo 'We are currently in Q'.$currentQuarter.' of '.date("Y")."\n";

$nextQuarter = $currentQuarter+1;
    
//check if our quarter is defined, if not it is probably '5' which means next year
if (!isset($quarters[$nextQuarter])) { 
    $nextQuarter = 1;
    $year = date("Y")+1;
} else {
    $year = date("Y");
}

echo 'The first day of the next quarter is '.date("Y-m-d", strtotime($year.'-'.$quarters[$nextQuarter]));
```

Here's a working sample: https://3v4l.org/2Mo4o